# Android dialog background with corner radius has layered background

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android, and really Java also.  In my app, I've got an alert dialog I'm throwing up that displays a date and time picker for the user to select a datetime they would like to send a message. That part is going fine.

In my xml, when I set a background attribute, which is currently blue and has a corner radius, there is seemingly an additional white background without a corner radius peeking out behind it.  I'm a little miffed.  Any help is appreciated.

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/corners_qk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:spinnersShown="false"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/corners"
    android:text="@string/picker_button"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

corners_qk.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
<solid
    android:color="@color/qkblue"/>
</shape>
```

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="qkblue">#2483d0</color>
</resources>
```

java:

```
final View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.date_time_picker, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
             TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

             Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                                datePicker.getMonth(),
                                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                                timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

             long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
             try {
                messageSend();
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});
    alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: post your @drawable/corners_qk

Comment: I have posted it now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the the background that you are seeing is the `default theme` of the `AlertDialog` which is `Light_THEME`, There is no way to make it transparent instead of using the AlertDialog just use the Dialog where you can make the its theme transparent.

**example:**

```
final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_time_picker);
    alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
             TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

             Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                                datePicker.getMonth(),
                                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                                timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

             long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        }});
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.show();
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: I see. Thanks very much Rod! I continue forward.