# Android Dialog with rounded corners - still showing the background without corners radius

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I want to make rounded corners dialog; but after I was done, it appears like this>>

[image: Result Design]

**Java**

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.complain_dialog);
final AlertDialog alertDialog= dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**The problem is:** why the dialog is still shown int the background without corners radius?

After searching for a solution to this problem, I found some of these solutions>>

1- [Android Dialog - Rounded Corners and Transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861310/android-dialog-rounded-corners-and-transparency)

2- [Android custom alert dialog with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781352/android-custom-alert-dialog-with-rounded-corners-and-transparent-background/21781509#21781509)

3- [Android dialog background with corner radius has layered background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197716/android-dialog-background-with-corner-radius-has-layered-background)

**Java- After test the above solutions**

```
Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.complain_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
dialog.show();
```

**Result after test the solutions**

[image: Result Design]

**Now the dialog is not appear at all! 
Can any one give me solution for this problem?** Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution with `AlertDialog` with same layout (tested On `Kitkat`).

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.temp);
 final AlertDialog alertDialog= dialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
 alertDialog.show();
```

To appear `Dialog` as same you need set the width of dialog. [Here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513616/android-get-full-width-for-custom-dialog). Otherwise it will take the Content width . Do all `dialog.getWindow()` operation before setting Content view to `Dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you tried,

```
Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.complain_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
dialog.show();
```

With the method `setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` you are basically making that view transparent.

You have to create a xml file with the shape and color of your drawable, something like from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122199/how-do-i-set-the-rounded-corner-radius-of-a-color-drawable-using-xml).

And then add it to your root element in your layout, so if your xml drawable (drawable folder) file that you just created is called `background.xml` your code would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And then just create the dialog normally, with no styles set from java, like originally:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.complain_dialog);
final AlertDialog alertDialog= dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below code on your app themes and make a drawable resource file for the corner radius

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_dilog</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#2c2f33</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#2c2f33</item>
    <item name="android:background">#f7eeed</item>
</style>
```

**For corner radius**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow tow line in your java code file

```
customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Also please update your layout like bellow

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You can add either `setBackgroundDrawable` or `setBackgroundDrawableResource`. Both do the same.